How can I balance between tidal locking and having high tides?
I am using Artifexian's WorldSmith, and what I am trying to achieve is having massive tides, but not having the planet being tidally locked to the moon (that would make tides useless!) Whenever I make the moon too massive, it tidally locks, and when I dont, the tides aren't as big as I'd like them to be. I am not restricting myself to Artifexian's (AMAZING) platform, and I am not concerned about doing calculations myself, so how do I achieve a solution?

Just how massive are you talking? Tidal locking doesn't happen all at once, there's potentially hundreds of millions of years involved (or longer). Can you specify a timeframe too?

(A) but not having the planet being tidally locked to the moon Later you say large moons tidally lock to the planet. May I assume the above statement is in error and that you meant to say, "but not having the moon being tidally locked to the planet?" I hope this is the case as it makes no sense to tidally lock a planet to its moon.  (B) I'm a bit confused by your issue. Do you want high tides and a non-tidally-locked moon? Physics be a harsh task master. What's your goal with a non-tidally-locked moon? Are we forced to deal with only one moon?

@JBH My goal is to have very big tides. My issue, is that the planet shows the same face to the moon, it gets tidally locked to the moon if I make the moon too big or too close. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

I have reread by reply and realized it is alsoo very confusing. The planet, gets tidlly locked to the moon when the moon is too big. I want, very very big tides, so big, that when I try to do it, the calculations say the planet gets tidally locked to the moon, but that not good.

OK. Please understand that when a "planet becomes tidally locked to its moon" what you really have is a binary planetary system. The problem is that physics and science are ruthless. There's a maximum limit to tides, after which everything becomes tidally locked (tidally locked binary planets) and the tides stop. You can get bigger tides if you ignore physics, which we're happy to embrace! But if you want to insist on physics, that limit is as good as you're going to get. Note that you can exacerbate tides locally with geology. That might get you part of the way there.

Good to know. Thank you!

Miller's planet in Interstellar seems to be tidally locked to its primary. Markedly prolate and probably on a markedly eccentric orbit, as well. Are its tides high enough for you?

@FrançoisJurain Miller's Planet in the movie Interstellar was not tidally locked in the way we are all thinking, which is why you had moving tides. If the same side of the planet always faced the black hole Gargantua without any thing else happening, a mountain of water would always be straining toward it... in the same place on the planet, at the point closest to Gargantua, never moving. As explained, planetary distortion is the cause of the waves (they're not tides)... and that's probably outside the OP's needs.

@JBH I have not read The science of Interstellar. I believe Miller's planet achieves 1 revolution around the BH in 1 of its sidereal days, which is the way I am thinking about tidal locking. I believe its rotation rate is not constant contrary to e. g. Earth, whence its tidal tsunamis. On Earth, the rate of change of the true anomaly is not constant, whence our equinoctial tides.

Sorry, "equinoctial tides" read: "winter tides", those spring tides reinforced once a yr, early in January, by the Sun being closest to the Earth.

Try an elliptical orbit. On Earth, tides are increased by a very small amount when the moon is closer to us, and the moon has an orbital eccentricity of about 0.055. I don't know if you could get truly massive tides with this, but increasing the eccentricity a substantial amount could produce tidal effects between tidally locked bodies. Of a sort, because your tides don't move, they just change in amplitude.
Not 100% sure of any of this but high eccentricity might also mess with how fast the sun appears to move across the sky. Which is cool! But might also mean you have to do more annoying math stuff.
Could result in fun time keeping systems though!
Oh also I wouldn't get super elliptical because I'm sure after a certain point the tidal forces (which also affect the inside of the planet) would probably cause issues i.e. widespread volcanism and the planet might not like getting squished around a bunch.

That is interesting. I'll check out the math for this, it sounds like it could work. Thank you!

Glad to help! And good call on checking the math; I'm not exactly a physicist.

I was thinking of suggesting an elliptical orbit for a different reason:  the planet can be tidally locked, yet undergo libration relative to the moon.  Basically the moon doesn't circle the planet as fast when it is far away, so it falls behind at that time, then catches up when it is near.  The result is that you have a tidally locked planet with huge tides.  But while I think that's what the poster wants, it doesn't fit the word of the request.

My propositions:

decrease the planet's density and increase its size. This would allow you to keep the atmosphere at a lower surface gravity, increase the angular inertia and increase the effect of the tidal forces.
Change the geography. Decrease the total surface of the oceans and the number of continents that can interact with the tidal bulge. Make the geography amplify the tides.
Make the moon younger. Maybe the moon was a captured dual planetoid? This is unlikely but could give you almost any tides you might want.


Here is a map of the average tide heights. The large tides are caused by resonances in the water basins - the water sloshes back and fourth, giving high tides where the basins resonate at the same frequency as the tidal forces from the moon. This gives tides that are three times as great as tides in the Pacific Ocean.
The tides are further magnified if you have an estuary or other formation that concentrates the flow of water into a narrowing channel. This is what gives the Severn Estuary the Severn Bore.
Are you wanting high tides everywhere? If your planet had polar continents and one giant equatorial ocean, you might have two giant waves that travelled all around the world with, and opposite to the moon. This might give you greater tide depths than we get on Earth, as the tides would not lose energy when the flow reverses.
Such a wave would have to travel at 1000 MPH to get around the Earth in a day. Tsunami travel at about half of that. You can increase the wave speed by increasing 'g' at the surface, but a heaver planet would be bigger, so the wave has further to go, so you are almost back where you started. A better solution would be to have the planet turn on its axis at half the speed, so the days are twice as long.
